# What's the proper way to split the cost of a shared Airbnb, with guests staying different lengths?

Tags: finance, economics

Example: A vacation house is rented for \$1000 for 10 days. Bob stays all 10 days, Alice stays 5 days. What does Bob charge Alice?

I thought of a few methods, but they differ. I'm not sure which to use.

Method 1:

Bob stays 10 nights, Alice stays 5. There are 15 "people nights".
\$1000 / 15 = \$66.66 per "people night".
Alice stayed 5 people nights, so she pays 5 x \$66.66 = $333.333

Method 2:

The nightly cost of the arrangement is \$100. For 5 days, it was split in half by Bob and Alice. So Alice pays 5 x (\$100 / 2) = \$250.

Which way is better? Ethically or mathematically?

Comment: This may be better suited at [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). This isn't really about maths and more about finding a compromise: it does matter if Bob and Alice are family or if they are complete strangers.

Comment: Method 2 seems right.  Something is wrong with Method 1 but I can't quite explain what it is.

Comment: @Ted The cost of an extra bed is marginal compared to renting the house. If there's someone staying in the Airbnb, it doesn't really matter if there is one person or two from the owner's perspective, so method 2 is fairer.

Comment: When Bob and Alice are staying in the house, the owner can't rent it out to anyone else for that time. The opportunity cost is the owner renting the house to someone who can pay more (which is why local residents hate this practice), which has nothing to do with Alice staying if Bob is staying as well.